# keeps display 10 whenever i refresh my browser even if it is already deducted localStorage

Tags: javascript, html

The problem is when I click on the button it reduces the slot and it's fine. Assuming that the remaining slot is 9, but when I refresh my browser it goes back to 10 but when I click again it is already 8, because I already deducted it earlier. My concern is that it always display the slot to 10 when I refresh the browser. I don't know why?

```
<script>
    var slot = localStorage.getItem("slot");

    if (slot == null) {
        slot = 10;
    }

    document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;

    function reduceSlot() {
        if (slot >= 1) {
            slot--;
            document.getElementById("slot").innerText = slot;
            localStorage.setItem("slot", slot);
        }
        else {
            document.getElementById('slot').innerText = "FULL";
            document.getElementById("button1").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    document.getElementById("button1").onclick = reduceSlot;

    function clearLocalStorage(){
        localStorage.clear();
    }
    </script>

<body>
<p id="slot">10</p>
<a href="javascript:reduceSlot(1)" id="button1">Deduct</a>
<button onclick="window.localStorage.clear();">Clear All</button>
</body>
```

I need your help for my assignment.

Comment: try paste your code in window.onload = function(){var slot = localStorage.getItem('slot') ... till reduceSlot(); problem could be caused by not existing of slot element, dom is not ready yet

Comment: @Dart it didn't worked sir need help

Comment: what about console? what it says. http://jsfiddle.net/K8stQ/, change launch option to onDomready and No wrap - head, or missing <head> tag

Comment: it has a `<head>` tag, yeah it works so fine in jsfiddle but in notepad then there is the problem. i don't know why

Comment: i don't know how to see look errors in console, i'm a newbie and still learning

Comment: f12 for chrome, right click -> inspect element for opera

Comment: it says Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerText' of null for console error

Comment: should be like that http://jsfiddle.net/K8stQ/2/, DOM is not ready when  javascript executes, so put javascript that is suppose to be executed after DOM ready, inside function, see window.onload on fiddle